# Does Google not allow to change CPU Frequency Governor on Google Cloud instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to change the CPU frequency scaling governor on my Google Cloud instance running Linux.

The usual way of setting it

`echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Doesn't work because the cpufreq folder does not exist (Inside cpu0/cpu1/cpu2/cpu3/cpu).

Tried installing cpufrequtils but still the folder did not show up. So is it that Google doesn't want too much power consumption from high CPU usage and disables it?

Comment: You are running in a virtualized environment. You cannot control the underlying hardware.

Comment: @JohnHanley, your comments worth answers, my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in a virtualized environment. You cannot control the underlying hardware.